# need help in submitting data using oop php to mysql database

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

Am using XAMPP for OS X 8.1.12 to create a project so i want to submit data using post to mysql database but the data is coming from mysql database bellow the codes that i have tried

```
     while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)) {
<td width="10%">
                                <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>" class="form-control">
                                <input type="hidden" name="so_detailId[]" value="<?php echo $quotation_detailsId; ?>" class="form-control">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"
                                                       min="0" max="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" name="issuedQuantity[]">
                                </td>
}
```

the above is code to submitted
and these bellow is the page where data are being sent before submitting to proccessing page

```
  $so_detailId = count($_POST['so_detailId']) ? $_POST['so_detailId'] : array();
$issuedQuantity = count($_POST['issuedQuantity']) ? $_POST['issuedQuantity'] : array();
```

the result i get is

```
Array
Array
```

instead of the value that is being inserted in the input.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show when you try to debug this code and work out what's going on?

Comment: I did not understand the question @ADyson

Comment: In that case it seems you do not understand the basics of [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) in your code. You need to learn to debug, so that you can fix problems when they occur. This is a basic skill you should have acquired as soon as you wrote a program more complicated then "hello world"! Otherwise you are like a plumber who can install a pipe but has no idea how to fix it when it leaks!! See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: What I want you to do is put the line `var_dump($_POST);` into your code, just above the `$so_detailId = count($_POST['so_detailId']) ? $_POST['so_detailId'] : array();` line. Then, run your code, and tell me what the output from the `var_dump` command was.  That way we can see what's actually in your $_POST array, which will help us to understand why it produced that output.

Comment: this what i get 
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "879" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" }

Comment: Ok thanks. So obviously, we can see that there are no items named "so_detailId" or "issuedQuantity". Did you expect that there should be? You only have numeric indexes.  It's unclear how this happened, based on the HTML you showed - but perhaps something extra happens in the form submissions which I cannot see. You can try to provide us with a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the case where there is no matching item, your code logic tells it to assign `array()` to `$so_detailId`. If you then try to save that to the database, you'll get `Array` (as you showed) because you cannot simply convert an array to a string - PHP has no way of knowing what you want it to look like as text, so it gives up and outputs "Array" instead. It's unclear what value you expected to see instead.

Comment: the thing is, it previously worked clearly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254175/discussion-between-edgar-inga-and-adyson).